# Is there a tool to combine multiple SVGs into one and use them as CSS Sprites?

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites

I would like to use a technique called CSS Sprites where you have a single image and you take advantage of `width`, `height` and `background-position` in CSS to display only parts of the image which combines a lot of smaller images. Do you know any good automated tool for this process?

Comment: Can you please clarify: once you combine the SVGs, do you want them as a single SVG file, or a single raster image (e.g. PNG)? And is this CSS being used with HTML, or SVG, or something else?

Comment: I want to make a single SVG file out of other smaller SVG files so that I can use the single SVG file for each CSS background image and use the property `background-position` to clip a part of it to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

(Not tested) Can you use a [XINCLUDE](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) processor to import your svg-icons as a [nested svg element](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Coordinates) ?